# Shutdown during recv on python socket

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, sockets, shutdown

During the execution of this code, it blocks on the join

I have a TCP server running on ("127.0.0.1", 1777) for the test

I tried using directly the socket with recv, but the result is the same

Any idea, why the shutdown on READ doesn't interrupt the read ?

```
import socket
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

class Parser(Thread):

    rbufsize = 4096
    wbufsize = 4096
    encoding="utf-8"
    new_line = "\n"

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._socket = socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET, type=socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self._wfile = None
        self._rfile = None
        
    def run(self):
    
        self._socket.connect(("127.0.0.1", 1777))
        self._rfile = self._socket.makefile('rb', self.rbufsize, encoding=self.encoding, newline=self.new_line)
        self._wfile = self._socket.makefile('wb', self.wbufsize, encoding=self.encoding, newline=self.new_line)
        while True:
            data = self._rfile.readline()
            
            if not data:
                break
            
            self._handle_data(data)
        
        self._cleanup()
           
    def _cleanup(self):
        """
        Fermeture
        """
        if not self._wfile.closed:
            try:
                self._wfile.flush()
            except socket.error:
                # A final socket error may have occurred here, such as
                # the local error ECONNABORTED.
                pass
        self._socket.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
        self._wfile.close()
        self._rfile.close()
        self._socket.close()

    
    def stop(self):
        self._socket.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RD)
        
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = Parser()
    p.start()
    sleep(5)
    p.stop()
    print("start join")
    p.join()
```

Comment: The thread is already in a sleep state waiting for I/O.  Calling shutdown in another thread won't wake the other thread up.  If the sleeping thead receives something, the *next* `recv` will fail for the socket being shutdown already.

Comment: I was expecting a similar behaviour with the C language (sorry for the formulation). It seems with a select the shutdown / close work as intended